# Counting bits in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have coded a linear feedback shift register of 5 bits. Trying to determine the strength of the key generated with a frequency test, counting the number of bits zero and one. But the count is completely incorrect. I don't know what is wrong in the code, here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
 for ( unsigned int freqo; freqo < keyRej.size(); freqo++)
  {
   if (keyRej[freqo] == 1) 
   { 
    count1 = count1 + 1;
   }
   else{count0 = count0 +1;}
  }
 cout << count1 << "\n";
 cout << count0 << "\n";
```

A link to the whole code: http://pastebin.com/sBMa0J5v

Comment: Where are you initialising count0 and count1?

Comment: I have initialized them in the beginning of main(), saying 'int count1, count0;'.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed so you are *not* initializing them, which is a problem

Comment: @MohamedAhmed your variables count0 and count1 contains dummy values if you declare them as local variable and not initialize them. So either declare them as global variable in which case they are automatically initialized to 0 or manually initialize them to 0

Comment: I have changed the declaration to 'int count1=0, count0=0;' and now both cout << cout1 and cout << cout0 return 0!

Comment: can you please post your whole code...

Comment: Why not use `std:;bitset`

Comment: Here is a [link] (http://pastebin.com/sBMa0J5v)

Comment: @NeilKirk I am already using it! Not sure what do you mean.

Comment: Not in this question you aren't. But you were when you asked this question yesterday. Why do you keep asking the same question with the same goal but slightly different code?

Comment: Finally, once again, you should be posting _testcases_, not "whole code" or tiny snippets. **Read http://sscee.org please**

Comment: I really do not know what am I doing wrong! I posted the whole code because one commentator asked me to do so. The link you provided is dead. Yesterday I asked about something else, I was trying to store bit 1 positions in an array. My whole purpose was to create a LFSR and I can't believe I did it, but I can't test using frequency test, the count is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In c++, variables are not set to zero by default.

I.e. you need to write `int count0 = 0`; to set `count0` to be zero initially. Similarly for `count1`.

In fact, to use a variable before initialising is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have inittialized the variables and now I get zeros for bot count1 and count0. I posted a link to the code (http://pastebin.com/sBMa0J5v)